# Xcode no account registered- but I have registered

Tags: xcode

I am new to the Xcode world.
I tried to build a project I was sent, and XCode says "There are no accounts registered with Xcode".
I then went online and signed up for a developer account (using my Apple ID / sole proprietor) - ouch, that was expensive.
Then I went back in to Xcode/Preferences/Accounts and added my Apple ID / Developer ID to the accounts.
I tried to rebuild the project - I get the same message.
I closed/reopened Xcode - same.
I restarted the Mac - same.

Does anyone know what step(s) I missed?

Thanks

Garrett

Comment: What region are you in?

Comment: West Canada (Vancouver)

Comment: clean your build.  Product => Clean Build Folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I re-installed Xcode, and re-registered my developer account, and then all was good.

p.s. Re-installing Xcode only took between 2 and 3 hours :(